# Problem with virtual env: can't import installed packages in the virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, virtualenv

I am doing some tests with virtualenv to see how it works and I think I ran into some trouble.

First I created a folder and changed my path to it:

```
$ mkdir new_folder 
$ cd new_folder
```

Then I created a virtualenv and activated it:

```
$ virtualenv my_first_venv
$ source my_first_venv/bin/activate
```

I installed only one package to make a test:

```
$ pip3 install wget
```

And I confirmed it was installed indeed:

```
(my_first_venv)    #this just shows up when you activate it
$pip list

Package    Version
------------------
pip        20.0.2
setuptools 41.2.0
wget       3.2
```

But if I create a .py file in that same path, and I write "import wget" and run it, I get an error message stating that there is no such module.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are running your Python code on global environment, instead of virtual environment which is `my_first_venv`. One way to do is to run your code using command prompt, after you have **activate** the virtual environment.

On Windows, script mode:

```
python <filename.py>
```

You can also run it in interactive mode, directly prompted a Python shell:

```
python -i <filename.py>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to do not have an alias for your python/pip command: an alias overlaps the venv commands. For instance, if you have an alias such as `python=python3`, then even if you are in your venv, the `python` command will execute the python alias command (in this example the python3 in your global environment) and not the python venv command.

Answer (score 1):

**After activating your virtual environment, try installing it with this instead**:

`python -m pip install wget`

or try using `pip install wget`

I'm guessing it's something to do with different `pip` versions talking to python outside your virtual environment. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing/importing a package from the system terminal (outside of the IDE/Text editor) using the same interpreter/environment.